# reading xml values as variables in XSL

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a XML properties file in diffent path and it is like

```
 <MyValues>
 <MyValue1>test</MyValue1>
</MyValues>
```

I would like to read MyValue1 in xslt,where i'm doing conversion for different XML,which is in different path.
My xsl is like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

 <xsl:variable name="GetMyValue" 

     select="${MyValue1}"/>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

how can i read MyValue1 from xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read in a secondary input file, then, given XSLT 2.0, you have the choice between the `doc` function and the `document` function. For a single file, `doc` suffices, so you can declare a global variable or parameter with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="input2" select="doc('dir/subdir/properties.xml')"/>` and then use that with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="GetMyValue" select="$input2/MyValues/MyValue1"/>`.

Comment: Hi, I checked it with my code.doc function is not reading the file in xml format.So I could not get output for eselect="$input2/MyValues/MyValue1".when i display input2,it is not in xml format.Do i need to add any output methods to get it as xml.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="MyValue1" select="document('dev.xml')/MyValues/MyValue1"/> is working.